# How to perform validation of json files with cuelang?

Tags: json, validation, schema, cuelang

I am evaluating cuelang.org to define data constraints, such as type or value checks on untrusted json payloads submitted to azure devops pipelines, before further processing.

When testing my definitions against invalid data I get no errors returned.

I want to have both type and value checks in place:

rules.cue:

```
#LoggingLinuxVM: {
  resource_id:  #NonEmptyString
  version:      =~"2020-07-21"
  type:         =~"Linux"
  properties:   #LoggingPropertiesLinuxVM
}

#LoggingPropertiesLinuxVM: {
  CustomLogFiles: [...#NonEmptyString]
}

#NonEmptyString: string & !=""
```

invalid payload (missing type)

```
{
  "resource_id": "/subscription/.../...",
  "version": "2020-07-21",
  "properties": {
    "custom_log_files": [
      "/var/log/dmesg",
      "/var/log/messages"
    ]
  }
}
```

when attempting to validate this with: `cue vet payload.json rules.cue` I expect to see validation errors, however none are raised and the exit status is 0 . Has anyone used cuelang in a similar fashion and can see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you have to provide the --schema flag to operate in the intended way. For this example, if the json were in payload.json the full command would be:

`cue vet --schema '#LoggingLinuxVM' payload.json rules.cue`

Comment: You can also embed the top-level schema in your CUE file, by writing the name without a colon after it. This then becomes the default schema for the file.

The `--schema` flag is handy if you want to put multiple schemas in a single file.